# Simple HTML internal link question

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, internal

Weired, simple HTML stuff didn't work as expected.
On page 1, a Railo script named page1.cfm,
it has the following line:
`<a href="page2.html#part2">Go To Page 2, Part 2</a>`
so, we expect the link would bring the user to the page2.html page's Part 2 section and yes this section and the internal link tag exists on page2.html.

But tested with Firefox 3.6.x, the link simply goes to the page2.html instead of the pag2.html's Part 2 section.  How come?

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simply a question of page-length, the view port can only scroll to have `#part2` section if the page *can* scroll.

Comment: the page1.cfm was opened from a javascript even trigger and not a full window, then, the page2.html located on the same window would share the same window properties.  So, it looks like that's the culprit.  How could we fix it?  The page1.cfm page has to be opened via javascript call.  Thanks.

Comment: If it was pure xhtml and css I could offer help, but sadly I know next-to-nothing about `cfm`. I'm assuming it's a version of Coldfusion? If you add the relevant generating program to your tags you might get more specific and *useful* help.

Comment: David, IE7 and Chrome 5 works fine but FF v3.6.8 has the problem probably it's FF's bug... further thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you look at the page in Firebug, or with the Web Developer toolbar? Is the page valid, does it have a Doctype, are there any JS errors reported?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issue with lower/uppercase, if the whole DOM is evaluated a duplicate entry named "part2" might lead to a similar error (check `name`-attribute as well as `id`). To get a better understanding of the problem, the exact code would be needed.

Comment: Ich checked for my other ideas "name vs. id" (jumps to the first mentioned id) and "many ids" (jumps to the first occurence). Neither one of them show similar issues like you mentioned. A piece of code would be very helpful to further investigate.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you were able to post a small section of code that demonstrates the problem.  Outside of that, there's a few general things you can try:

- Try to see if you can reproduce the bug that you're currently experiencing in FF with just straight HTML & Javascript.  (I'm going to guess - 'No')
- Try to reproduce the bug using the smallest possible test case with your .CFM files.
- Check any/all of your Javascript with [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).
- Check FireFox's [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) for any known .cfm issues.

Often, just starting to isolate the issue can highlight little unseen problems that allow you to solve it quickly. If the bug persists, let us know, and we can go from there....

Cheers.

Comment: oh, it's possible that the fact that the html code is well formed could be the culprit.

Comment: continued, the code looks like: <p><a href="page2.html#part2">Go to Page 2 Part 2</a></p>, and that's it.  No header or anything else.  I'll try to add standard "header" etc. HTML code when boot up that box, thanks.

Comment: @Don Were you able to correct the formatting issues, and test again?

Comment: @S Jones, thanks for asking, I opted to a workaround, that is, detect browser first, if FF then, not to use EXT window for the second page.